# Realtime Chart in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, recharts

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Line, LineChart, XAxis, YAxis } from 'recharts';

import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://192.168.1.45:4001';
function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
  const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('a', (a) => {
      updateData((currentData) => {
        const ab = [...currentData, a];
        return ab.length <= 200 ? ab : ab.splice(1);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>size of data is :- {data.length}</h1>
      <LineChart width={1000} height={500} data={data}>
        <XAxis dataKey='name' />
        <YAxis />
        <Line dataKey='value' />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Up here is the code for real-time chart in react I am having a socket.io connection and the server is emitting at least 150 values per second. Chart is working fine on the first 60 seconds but after that, it start lagging. I can't able to pinpoint the issue here.

I asked this before also where Nick helped me achieve this result, but it's not smooth yet.
help is much appreciated

Comment: I guess at 150 updates / sec, the browser gets quite stressed copying arrays every single time and running React. I think you'd need something more optimised. Maybe try using a circular array structure, and throttling the react updates down?

Comment: I don't think circular array will able to help how will it help in optimiazation

Comment: Maybe there are other bottlenecks I don't know because I can test this, but your code is allocating 150 arrays of 200 elements every second, which I guess it might be one of the bottlenecks. Using a circular array you'd be able to reuse the same memory space, essentially removing all the allocations... The only problem is that recharts only takes regular arrays, in which case you'd have to convert, but at most, 30 times per second (5 times less).

Comment: I've seen in your other question you said you needed to do the (at least) 150 times per second because it's real time. In web, most of the time 30fps is enough, and when dealing with charting libraries IMO it's ok to even dip to 5-10fps, as drawing data takes time on a JS+DOM runtime. For this reason, I think that the best strategy is that although you process the data 150 times per second (because you don't want to skip values), you only "call react" less times - just when the browser is ready to paint (see requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: will see it if can do anything